# Flutter fullscreen app - status bar still taking space

Tags: flutter

i am trying to make a full screen flutter app.

```
Future<void> main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: []);
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,

  ));
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: green),
        useMaterial3: true
      ),
      home:  Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

it hide the status bar but still taking space as black.The red color container not taking the space of status bar.
[image]

Comment: Could you please add more info, also check if you might be using a SafeArea widget, and add code to review

Comment: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: creamColor,)... but the space of status bar look black

Answer (score 0):

Please try it using the following way :

```
void main() async {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky, overlays: []);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        extendBody: true, 
        body: const YourMainWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: not working, still shows a black space in the space of status bar

Answer (score 0):

I also have a fullscreen app, this is what my code looks like:
(Make sure to not use SafeArea() widget)

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => Bloc1(),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => Bloc2(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          extendBody: true,
          extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
          body: HomeScreen(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Try to use SystemChrom.setEnabledSystemUiMode inside your build method, not on main(). Also, set `extendBodyBehindAppBar` to true.

Comment: not working , checked in realme 9 pro android 13

Comment: @TheCodes So I guess you're messing something in somewhere else, because it works perfectly fine on darpad. You can go on and test it by yourself, just paste the code on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev)